# Adding 2nd level variable into Multi-level Modelling in Stata

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis

I'm used to HLM 7 software and now I'd like to switch to Stata, for multilevel modelling (xtmixed).

To give an example imagine I have students(level1) nested within schools (level2).
In HLM I can easily add a second level variable (for instance schools beauty) choosing the equation of a coefficient (or intercept) which is at level 2.

Imagine I want to include the effect of school beauty in B0 (intercept).
How can I do that in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here:

http://www.iub.edu/~statmath/stat/all/hlm/hlm.pdf

The answer is:

> whereas HLM requires two separate data les (one corresponding to each level), SPSS, Stata, SAS, and R rely on only a single file. The level-2 observations are common to each
>   case within the same macro-unit, so that if there are 50 students in one school the
>   corresponding school-level score appears 50 times. Each program also requires an id
>   variable identifying the group membership of each individual.

So, adding a second level variable to the model, like the school sector (Sector), can be easily done via the `xtmixed` command. For instance:

```
xtmixed MatGrade Intelligence Sector || SchoolId:
```

Where "MatGrade" is the outcome variable, "Intelligence" is a level 1 variable reflecting the intelligence of the scholars. Scholars are nested within schools.